# How I can check if get_theme_mod is in header or a template part

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am using [understrap theme](https://github.com/understrap/understrap) and [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com) in a website and I want to alter the default understrap's container type behaviour. I created a custom field to override the theme container type in a specific page while I keep the one I selected everywhere else.

As I can see the theme uses:

```
$container = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_container_type' );
```

in **header.php**, **footer.php**, **page.php**, **single.php** etc.

I created a new filter like this:

```
add_filter( 'theme_mod_understrap_container_type', 'override_container_type' );
function override_container_type() {
    if ( get_field('container_type') ) {
        return get_field('container_type');
    }
    else {
        return get_theme_mod( 'understrap_container_type' );
    }
}
```

While I only want to alter it in the `<main>` section and not header or footer, how I can check inside this function if is in header or main content?
I tried `if ( ! did_action( 'get_header' ) )` but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried `if ( ! did_action( 'get_header' ) )` but doesn't seem to work.

Try again, but this way:

```
add_filter( 'theme_mod_understrap_container_type', 'override_container_type' );
function override_container_type( $value ) {
    if ( did_action( 'get_header' ) && ! did_action( 'get_footer' ) ) {
        if ( get_field('container_type') !== 'inherit' ){
            return get_field('container_type');
        }
    }

    // For header.php and footer.php
    return $value;
}
```

So basically, here's the *conditional* you need:

```
did_action( 'get_header' ) && ! did_action( 'get_footer' )
```

---

### UPDATE

If you are using a *child theme*, how about these:

Add this to `functions.php`:

```
function my_theme_container_type( $location = null ) {
    if ( 'main' === $location ) {
        if ( $value = get_field('container_type') ){
            return $value;
        }
    }

    return get_theme_mod( 'understrap_container_type' );
}
```

Edit the `single.php` and `page.php` files, and change this:

```
$container = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_container_type' );
```

to

```
$container = my_theme_container_type( 'main' );
```

And remove this (from `functions.php`):

```
add_filter( 'theme_mod_understrap_container_type', 'override_container_type' );
function override_container_type() {
    ...
}
```

That may not answer the question, but I'd do that if I were you. =)

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that I can get $value there. Thanks for that... I tried it but it is also change the value on header in this specific page. I tried to echo inside this if and it echos after <body> tag :/

Comment: Do you actually use a *child theme*?

Comment: Yes but why? the filter is in parent functions and didnt touch any header.php

Comment: *I tried to echo inside this if and it echos after <body> tag* - yes because at that point, `get_header()` has already been called.

Comment: *Yes but why?* - see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer but I dont want to alter the understrap default behavior and all templates :(

Comment: In that case, then hopefully (someday) the theme author could change the theme mod key to something like `$container = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_container_type-' . {the template file name like single.php} );` or you know, something that could let us know where the theme mod is being retrieved from. Anyway, thanks for the vote-up. :)

Comment: Thank you for giving time to this... I think that this did_action don't help here. Is there any other action which gets the template part

Comment: Sorry, forget about what I said before.. If you mean something like what WooCommerce offers like `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );` and `do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );`, then no, the UnderStrap theme doesn't currently provide such 'actions'. But like I've mentioned before, if you don't want to *override* the standard/built-in UnderStrap templates, then you can use JavaScript to change the container's `class`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! I think i have to skip this feature for this time! I thought that it will be easier :(

Comment: Any idea where they moved this filter at the latest version?

Comment: They who and which filter - the WooCommerce filters? But actually, you could just try finding the filter in the plugin or theme source/codebase..

Comment: Nevermind I forget that you can add_filter( ‘theme_mod_*’ ) to any mod